# Change state of mapped favorite buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble with a favorite button in my app.

I have set it up to save the data in a favorites array in my database, and can display that data in a separate component. The issue I am having is when I press the button it changes every button in the mapped data.

Here is the code for the button

```
export default function ShowRecords() {
  const classes = recordFormStyles();
  const url = " http://localhost:5000/record";

  //get userData state to use in useEffect

  //set state for showing records in database and opening/closing modals

  const [newRecords, newRecordData] = React.useState([]);

  const [editOpen, handleEditModal] = React.useState(false);

  const [addModalOpen, handleAddModal] = React.useState(false);

  //set state for edit records

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");

  const [artist, setArtist] = React.useState("");

  const [rating, setRating] = React.useState("");

  const [genre, setGenre] = React.useState("");

  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");

  const [userId, setUserId] = React.useState("");

  //set state for favorite icon

  const [favorite, setFavorite] = React.useState([]);



  //functions to control state

  const handleAddModalOpen = () => {
    handleAddModal(true);
  };

  const handleCloseAddModal = () => {
    handleAddModal(false);
  };

  const handleIsEditModalClose = () => {
    handleEditModal();
  };

  //fetch record data

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/record/get",
      authToken
    );
    newRecordData(result.data);
    console.log(result.data);
  };

  //check if favorite is in local storage

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();

    console.log("data");
  }, []);

  // see if user is logged in already, if not set a token and userData

  // delete records

  const deleteRecord = async (_id) => {
    const deleteRecords = {
      _id: newRecords._id,
      title: newRecords.title,
      artist: newRecords.artist,
      rating: newRecords.rating,
      genre: newRecords.genre,
      description: newRecords.description,
    };

    await axios
      .delete("http://localhost:5000/record/" + _id, deleteRecords)
      .then((result) => {
        const refresh = newRecords.filter((result) => result._id !== _id);
        newRecordData(refresh);
      });
  };

  //functions for controlling edit record state

  const editRecord = (_id, title, artist, rating, genre, description) => {
    setUserId(_id);
    setTitle(title);
    setArtist(artist);
    setRating(rating);
    setGenre(genre);
    setDescription(description);
    handleEditModal(true);

    console.log(title);
  };

  //functions for setting favorite state and color and post request to add favorite

  const deleteFavorite = (_id) => {
    setFavorite([]);
  };

  // post request to add favorite

  const handleFavorite = (_id, title, artist, rating, genre, description) => {
    const favorites = {
      _id: _id,
      title: title,
      artist: artist,
      rating: rating,
      genre: genre,
      description: description,
    };

    const addFavorite = () => {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/favorite/add", favorites, authToken)
        .then((res) => localStorage.setItem("favorite", res.data));
    };

    addFavorite();
    setFavorite(title);

    console.log(title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* set props */}

      <Favorites />
      <AddRecord
        isAddModalOpen={addModalOpen}
        handleIsAddModalClose={handleCloseAddModal}
        addNewRecords={newRecords}
        handleIsAddModalOpen={handleAddModal}
        refreshRecordData={newRecordData}
      />
      <EditRecords
        editModalOpen={editOpen}
        handleCloseEditModal={handleIsEditModalClose}
        editUserId={userId}
        editTitle={title}
        editArtist={artist}
        editRating={rating}
        editGenre={genre}
        editDescription={description}
        editTitleState={setTitle}
        editArtistState={setArtist}
        editRatingState={setRating}
        editGenreState={setGenre}
        editDescriptionState={setDescription}
        editUrl={url}
        editFetchData={fetchData}
        editNewRecordData={newRecordData}
      />
      <Button
        className={classes.addButton}
        onClick={() => handleAddModalOpen(true)}
      >
        Add Record
      </Button>

      <div className={classes.cardsContainer}>
        <Grid container spacing={10} style={{ padding: "24px" }}>
          {newRecords.length > 0 &&
            newRecords.map((element) => (
              <Grid key={element._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4} xl={2}>
                <Card className={classes.root}>
                  <CardContent>
                    <>
                      {favorite ? (
                        <IconButton
                          onClick={() => deleteFavorite(!favorite)}
                          className={classes.favoriteOn}
                        >
                          {" "}
                          <StarRateIcon className={classes.favoriteYellow} />
                        </IconButton>
                      ) : (
                        <IconButton
                          onClick={() =>
                            handleFavorite(
                              element._id,
                              element.title,
                              element.artist,
                              element.rating,
                              element.genre,
                              element.description
                            )
                          }
                          className={classes.favoriteOff}
                        >
                          {" "}
                          <StarOutlineIcon
                            className={classes.favoriteGrey}
                          />{" "}
                        </IconButton>
                      )}
                    </>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6">
                      {element.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Artist: {element.artist}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Rating: {element.rating}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Genre: {element.genre}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" component="p">
                      Description: {element.description}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>

                  <CardActions>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() =>
                        editRecord(
                          element._id,
                          element.title,
                          element.artist,
                          element.rating,
                          element.genre,
                          element.description
                        )
                      }
                      size="small"
                      color="inherit"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => deleteRecord(element._id)}
                      size="small"
                      color="inherit"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried assigning an _id, or title or whatever to the setFavorite() method. This will Toggle the individual card, but if I click on the button it will toggle the rest of the buttons in the mapped data. I have tried making the button have its on state like this

```
const [click, setClick] = React.useState(false)
```

As you can see I have tried saving it to localStorge, not sure if I am doing that right.

this does the exact same thing.

So my question is how, how do i control the state of the button in my mapped data, so it will persist through my app?? I hope this makes sense, I am very new to all of this and am stuck on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to provide the whole component code

Comment: Why is your `favourite` variable initialized as an array but later set as undefined?

Comment: I included the whole code the component

Comment: Also, I have it set to an array to save it to the datababse. I simply was trying things and forget to set it back on delete. That has nothing to do with my question though

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out on my own as well, I am learning....

This is for anyone with the same question, which I could not find the answer too.

I simply moved the button to its own component, and let that component control the state. I was making things way to complicated